# What is the SLA for Azure Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I've been seeing long latency recently (up to 30-50 secs) calling Azure Graph API from its SDK client. Including query account, add account, adding group members and get account photo. Is there a SLA document for Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no SLA at this time for the either the Azure AD Graph nor the Microsoft Graph.**

You can always ask for this via the [Microsoft Graph feedback forum](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).